# Sending emails with django renders does not renders them as expected in gmail

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I`m using Django to send some emails with embedded images to my gmail account. The problem is that when I receive the email, all the images are shown as attachments and I have to click "Display images below" to make them appear in the template and even then they are still shown under it.

I don't want to see the attached images below the template, that's all.

In Thunderburd and some other email clients, the template renders perfectly, but in gmail it just fails.

I`m following this tutorial: [Displaying inline images on iPhone, iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103210/displaying-inline-images-on-iphone-ipad)

This is the template that I`m using: http://pastebin.com/tUen272b

All the attached images are used in it.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmail recently got a little more agressive with hiding images by default, you likely have to select "always show images from" in order to have the images show up without intervention. as far as why they aren't showing up in the correct place, no clue, IF, as you say, they display correctly in other clients.

Do you have the template HTML?