# Embed an image in html for automatic outlook365 email send

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp

I am trying to embed and image in my html code using smtp and email in python. 
Packages are:
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

This is the snippet in the html

```
<img border=0 width=231 height=67 src="Hello_files/image001.png">
```

This is what I see in the actual email send
[image]

I feel like I am doing something very wrong that is probably obvious to most.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying inline images on iPhone, iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103210/displaying-inline-images-on-iphone-ipad)

Comment: Nope not a duplicate. They are getting two I am getting none

Comment: Can you post the code you're using with smtplib? @megv

Answer (score 2):

Based on your HTML snippet I'll take a swing at this.

**Your HTML**

```
<img border=0 width=231 height=67 src="Hello_files/image001.png">
```

You're referencing the image as it appears in your local filesystem but in the context of the email in a recipient's computer, that directory and file name won't exist.

**Example HTML**

```
<img src='cid:image1' alt='image' style="display: block;margin: auto;width: 100%;">
```

Here we reference the image as **cid:image1**.  In our python code, we load the image and encode it to match up with our html.  In the example below, the image *test.png* is in the same directory as our python script.

**Example MIME Image Encoding**

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
s.starttls()
s.login('email','password')

msg = MIMEMultipart()  # create a message

email_body = "<img src='cid:image1' alt='image' style="display: block;margin: auto;width: 100%;">"

# Read and encode the image
img_data = open('./test.png', 'rb').read()
image = MIMEImage(img_data)
image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msg.attach(image)

# Construct the email
msg['From']='swetjen@someplace.com'
msg['To']='swetjen@someplace.com'
msg['Subject']='My email with an embedded image.'

msg.attach(MIMEText(email_body, _subtype='html'))

s.send_message(msg)
```