# Mail sent using send_mail() [Python - Django] does not send embedded images

Tags: python, html, django, email

Okay so following is my email template:

```
<html>

<head>
{% load staticfiles %}

</head>

<body>

<h2>Welcome!</h2>
<img src = "{% static 'app/images/logo1.png' %}" style = "position: absolute; left: 5%; height: 100%; width:50%;" />


<div style = "position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0%; height: 10%; width: 100%: color: #006699;"></div>

<img src = "{% static 'app/images/content.png' %}" style = "position: absolute; left:0%; top: 110%; height: 100%; width: 60%">
</img>
</body>

</html>
```

Following is my email function:

```
        html_template = render_to_string('email_template.html', {})

        try:
            send_mail(
                'Title',
                'Plaintext Version Goes Here',
                'sender',
                [email],
                html_message=html_template,
            )
        except:
            return HttpResponse("No!")
```

When I send the mail only Welcome! is printed in the mail. The images do not show up. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this specified the full STATIC_URL, e.g http://localhost:8000/static/
and when deployed, i changed to the domain.
Try to change it to

```
<img src = "http://localhost:8000/static/app/images/logo1.png" style = "position: absolute; left: 5%; height: 100%; width:50%;" />
```

I have found this [possible other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787755/django-how-to-send-html-emails-with-embedded-images) but i don't tried.

Comment: if him are in development and is testing the email, why not ?

Comment: Sorry.  Never was a strong word. It is not recommended though.