# Gmail's broken image links when sending mails through Django

Tags: image, amazon-s3, gmail

I'm sending an email using the SMTP protocol in Django. When I send the image link it is like this:

```
https://example.com/images/pic1.jpg
```

But Gmail converts it to something like this:

```
https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/vI79kajdUGm6Wk-fjyicDLjZbCB1w9NfkoZ-zQFOB2OpJ1ILmSvfvHmE56r72us5mIuIXCFiO3V8rgkZOjfhghTH0R07BbcQy5g=s0-d-e1-ft#https://example.com/images/pic1.jpg
```

I tried the image URL proxy whitelist setting. It is showing the preview of the image.But image links are not working.
[image: img link broken]

PS: I have also tried methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter) to no avail.

**Update 1:**
The images are stored in the AWS s3 bucket. If I make them public then they work fine. But I can't make them public.Is there any other way?

Comment: you can set cors headers in AWS S3. Aslo please provide more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The images are stored in the AWS s3 bucket. If I make them public then they work fine. But I can't make them public.Is there any other way?

The short answer is "no" if you want to keep referencing image through URLs as GMail's image proxy needs access to your images over the "public" internet one way or another.

This question is a bit off topic as it has little to do with Django but if you're using GMail for business [you can configure which URLs should not go through the proxy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041?hl=en). This should allow you to prevent images served from your "private" S3 bucket URL from being proxied. Note that this will only work for GMail accounts within your business domain; the images will be proxied and fail to load if the email is sent to a non-business or a different business Gmail account for example.

One another way you could avoid proxying completely it to attach the image in the email instead of referring to it through an URL. You can refer to this answer for how to achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787766/70191.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Simon. I already tried the proxy whitelist method. It is showing me the image preview in my google workspace account. But when I send mail from my custom domain to someuser@gmail.com then I'm encountering this problem. I also tried the second method, but it did not look nice since images were attached at the bottom of the mail body.

Comment: Are there any settings like CORS or server configuration that I can perform to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: > But when I send mail from my custom domain to someuser@gmail.com then I'm encountering this problem.
yeah this won't work for recipients outside the domain your own.
> I also tried the second method, but it did not look nice since images were attached at the bottom of the mail body.
It should work if you define your images with `src="cid:..."` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171742/send-e-mail-to-gmail-with-inline-image-using-python. Otherwise you could try base `base64` images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279523/base64-images-to-gmail

Comment: The second method worked but the mail size is increased after I added images as attachments. I want to create a reference URL for the images without attaching them.

Comment: How do other companies perform it? Adding user images in the newsletter without attaching them like LinkedIn and other social sites.

Comment: They simply serve their images from a publicly accessible location. I think you should revisit your decision of not making your S3 bucket accessible publicly through HTTP. If you don't want it to be public because you're stashing private data in there as well create two distinct buckets for your two different purposes.

Comment: Hey Simon,I'm facing this issue again. Wonder if you could help me out here?

Comment: I have made my bucket public and serving images using a custom domain.But still, Gmail showing the above behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related but we saw the same problem recently.  We had an AWS WAF global setting with two rules:

- AWS-AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList
- AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet

These rules were suggested as part of our SOC2 efforts.  Out of the blue (it's been working for months), the reputation list rule started blocking Google's Image Proxy service.  We made a rule to allow the image proxy service and it solved the problem.

Note that we have images stored in an S3 bucket with a CloudFront distribution and the WAF settings were tied to CloudFront.